# MASM32 Overwriting a file using assembly

Tags: assembly, file-io, masm, masm32

I'm currently doing an encryption in some of my files as an exercise. However, I'm having a trouble in overwriting a .txt file and having a hard time identifying what went wrong. Below is the part of the code I've been working on which I think has the problem.

```
  push 0
  push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
  push OPEN_EXISTING
  push 0
  push 0
  push FILE_READ_DATA
  push offset fData.cFileName
  call CreateFile

  mov hndl, eax

  push 0
  push hndl
  call GetFileSize

  mov fSize, eax

  push 0
  push offset bfrLen
  push fSize
  push offset bfr
  push hndl
  call ReadFile

  push hndl
  call CloseHandle

  lea esi, bfr
  mov al, [esi]
  cmp al, 7fh
  jg skip
  encrypt:
    mov al, [esi]
    xor al, 0ffh
    mov [esi], al
    inc esi
    mov al, [esi]
    cmp al, 00h
    jne encrypt

  push 0
  push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
  push CREATE_ALWAYS
  push 0
  push 0
  push FILE_WRITE_DATA
  push offset file
  call CreateFile

  mov hndl, eax

  push offset bfr
  call lstrlen

  push 0
  push offset bfrLen
  push fSize
  push offset bfr
  push hndl
  call WriteFile

  push hndl
  call CloseHandle

  skip:
    ret
```

Review my code, guys! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a debugger and a syscall tracer. Add error handling to your program. Also, comment your code especially if you want others to help. Give more details than "having a trouble", describe what happens. That said, `push WriteFile` is very suspicious, didn't you mean `call WriteFile`?

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thanks. However the code still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, your `jg skip` is suspicious, it skips everything including writing out the file. Hard to tell whether you want that or not, with the limited information you provided. "doesn't work" is still not better than "having a trouble". See also [ask].

Comment: I'm sure it does "work", it just probably does not do what you did want or expect. Similar code usually doesn't stop CPU from executing it and it will do **something**. Often by using debugger you can overview what is that "something".

Comment: _"having a hard time identifying what went wrong"_ Check every return value, and call `GetLastError` if a WinApi function returns something other than "success".

Comment: `CreateFile` can fail for tons of reasons, like wrong file name, wrong path (extremely common problem), wrong permissions, already open, etc., etc. And you don't check for any of those!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov al, [esi]
> cmp al, 7fh
> jg skip
> ```

This is a useless test! Nothing can ever be **greater** (signed byte) than 127.
Perhaps you meant to test for the **above** (unsigned byte) condition?

```
cmp byte [esi], 7Fh
ja  skip             ;Skip if from 128 to 255
```

---

Just a thought. Maybe this test must be *repeated with each iteration*? We can't possibly know these details of your task.